# Securing script injection and execution on third party iframes

Tags: javascript, security

I want to be able to inject scripts into an iframed page (hosted on a 3rd party server) within a page served out of my own server (to visualize changes for a `wysiwyg`app).

Since I have a small stub script on the 'target' page, I could I guess just have a method that allows arbitrary script execution of whatever is passed to it. Obviously this doesnt sound like something that is secure, since it would open an attack vector for some neat XSS. One of the ideas I had for securing it was passing some sort of token alongside the scripts I want to run, which the  stub client code would check with a server, and only then execute scripts. Does this make sense? Could anybody point me to any precedents perhaps?

Many thanks

Comment: Is there no other way to solve this? The iframe solution sounds... risky.

Comment: it does a bit -- but since i need to show changes live, the only other solution i can think of is proxying the pages via my server. That is not going to be cool (url re-writing, loads of bw etc)

Comment: How are you going to get to this proposed script in the "target" page? The browser is not going to let you touch it at all.

Comment: I have a small stub script on them, i can just add a method get_script_from_url_and_execute(url) etc. and pass the url via querystring when i load the url in the iframe i guess

Comment: Well, if *your* code can pass in a script through an HTTP parameter, then *anybody* can. Whether that's a good thing or a bad thing depends  on the content.

Comment: Point taken. Is there any way to make this safe?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First off, it sounds like you control a small amount of code in the actual iFrame.  Rather than your proposal of allowing others to inject a script via that stub (which would open you up to all sorts of attacks), why don't you put the actual "safe" code that you want in the iframe and then just notify a parent frame of the results?

Second off, there are a zillion web pages written about safe cross-domain iframe communication.  Since I'm still not sure exactly what you're trying to do, you may need to just do the searching yourself and find the mechanism that works best for you.  A Google search for "safe cross domain iframe communication" finds a ton of information.

Third, the article I came across and liked the best is [Cross Domain Communication with iFrames](http://softwareas.com/cross-domain-communication-with-iframes) and the safest technique looks like [postMessage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.postMessage) because it shares data only, doesn't allow code calling and can actually check for origins that it trusts, though postMessage is only available in newer browsers so you would have to fall back to one of the other techniques that works in older browsers too.  Here's a [jQuery plugin](http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-postmessage-plugin/) that uses postMessage when available and falls back to another technique when not.

If this info isn't enough, then please tell us more about what you're trying to do in the iFrame or what information you're trying to pass between the two origins?

Comment: I think this is about as close to an answer as is feasible, given the question.

Comment: Great, thank you very much -- there was loads on the interwebs, but wanted to make sure i wasnt missing something obvious :). Turns out, to some extent I was, all I need is a trigger (now that I think about it) rather than arbitrary code execution :). Cheers for the links, these will come in handy!